# Question regarding vector calculus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, integration, vector-fields, navier-stokes

Question regarding vector calculus:

[image]

Mathematically, what properties does this vector field have, in order for its line integral to be equal to the area enclosed by that curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an application of stokes theorem

Consider

$\oint \vec{F} \cdot \vec{dr}$

= $ \iint \nabla × \vec{F} \cdot \vec{da}$

Now, if:

$\nabla × \vec{F} = 1\hat k$

This line integral will be:

$ \iint 1\hat k \cdot \vec{da}$

For a curve in the xy plane the surface attached to it is chosen to be a flat one.

This surface is also the area enclosed.

The $\vec{da}$ element will be $|\vec{da}| \hat k$

Plugging in:

$ \iint 1\hat k \cdot |\vec{da}| \hat k $

$\iint |\vec{da}|$

Which is just the area enclosed by the curve.

Prove that your vector fields curl is 1, and you've proven it for all curves.

Comment: Thanks a lot jensen